# Get sum of particular column of filtered rows only of material ui datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

this is my code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/filtered-rows-sum-rs5jz6?file=/src/App.js

I have to implement the sum of "Amount" column when user choose the in-built filter.ex-if user choose "JLI" then I want sum of amount of JLI station only.